# How to get user logs in Windows Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, logging, azureportal

Is it possible to get user activity regarding creating and deleting VMs in Windows Azure Portal? Do any logs for these operations exist?

Comment: Please check audit logs in Azure Portal. HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri i saw this option in new version of Azure Portal but i tried to create and delete VM and i didn't see there are any info about my actions.

Comment: Did you perform these operations in the new portal or old portal?

Comment: @GauravMantri old portal i thought it not depend on portal version because i can see info about backup service for example

Comment: Please check operation logs in the old portal. They can be found under management services.

Comment: @GauravMantri you are right there are all info that i need! you can move your comment to answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resources you manage (create/update/delete) via old portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com), please check `Operation Logs`. You can find this under `Management Services` section there.

[image]

For resources you manage via new portal (https://portal.azure.com). please check `Audit Logs`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the new Azure Resource Manager (ARM) to create VMs, please refer to [Azure Activity Logs within Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-activity-logs).